# MySQL: What to do if table reached max number of records?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, architecture

If I were to create a mysql table (innodb) and I reached the maximum number of records that can be added (not sure about the exact figures, billions or more?) what will happen aside from I cannot add a new record? How could I resolve this problem?

I know it would take years for a table to reach its limit but looking forward, what is the best way to avoid this kind of instance?

Comment: Here [Limits on InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

Comment: Take a look at partitioning

Comment: You will have _many_ other scaling problems before you hit the 64TB limit.  Indexing will become an issue.  UUIDs will become totally useless.  You will run out of money to expand your hardware.  But query optimization will probably be your biggest headache.

Comment: Partitioning can get you past 64TB since each partition is effectively a "table".  (Unless "native partitioning" leads to an overall 64TB limit.)

Comment: [More limits](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are working for Google or NSA, you shouldn't be running in such problems. The maximum number of records in a table (if we ignore the direct file-size limitations) would be tied to your primary keys.

But, since you should already be using `SERIAL` (which is alias of `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`), the maximum value of it would be 
18446744073709551615.

Storing a filled table, with just one column like this, would require ~150EB (before compressions). That's 1500000 TeraBytes.

Comment: Yes, I am using `SERIAL` for primary keys. So it seems that I wouldn't worry much with regards to it reaching the max number of records since it rely mostly on disk space.

Answer (score 1):

The only applicable limit would be the maximum table size of 64TB as shown [on their site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

The solution to avoid reaching that or other possible hardware limitations, mainly disk space, is archiving.  Archiving is simply to routinely extract older records and insert them in other tables that you call archives with a date, and of course remove them from the original table.

Note that the archiving is done on older records.  You want to keep recent records available.  Therefore, it is usually done at regular intervals such as every 6 months, keeping the 3 last months.

This process can also cause a performance improvement in certain cases.

Comment: 64TB is really large. I wonder how many rows that could hold? Anyway, if my understanding is correct, do you mean to have this kind of structure: Main table is `products` then when I reached 1 million rows, I archive it by creating another table `products-20160429` so `products` table is now empty again? How about the `products.id` issue?

Comment: Okay, so does that mean that you'll just move the records to `products-20160429` and `products` table will still increment to the last id? Let's say the last `product.id` = 4000 in which will be moved to the archive so `products.id` will have the next number as 4001 as its first record?

Comment: Yes.  You **must** also preserve the ids in the archived tables in case you need to consult them.

Comment: Okay. But then, if `product.id` 2000 is in `products-20160429` and `products.id` is related to `orders.id`, how could `orders.id` reference to `products-20160429`?

Comment: That is why archiving should be done according to business rules.  Archives are kept for reference only for things that shouldn't normally be needed.  Where I work, they only keep the last 3 months for most things in the live tables except billing related stuff which is kept active for a year.

Comment: Do the math.  You don't have a fire hose big enough to squirt 64TB of data into a single table within a year.